# Get and send id tagfield values. Extjs

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs6

There are two fields in the grid:

```
...
{
                    text: 'Спец. учетка',
                    sortable: true,
                    dataIndex: 'specuserName',
                    flex: 2,
                    editor: {
                        xtype: 'combobox',
                        store: 'Vendors',
                        displayField: 'name',
                        valueField: 'name',
                        //editable: false,
                        queryMode: 'remote',
                        //forceSelection: true,
                        triggerAction: 'all',
                        allowBlank: true
                    }
                },
                {
                        header: 'Сотрудники группы',
                        dataIndex: 'users',
                        flex:2,
                        editor: {
                            xtype: 'tagfield',
                            typeAhead: true,
                            queryMode: 'remote',
                            filterPickList: true,
                            triggerOnClick: true,
                            displayField: 'name',
                            valueField: 'name',
                            triggerAction: 'all',                          
                            store: 'IntraUsers',

                        }
                },
...
```

ViewController looks like that:

```
Ext.define('App.view.MainIntranetController', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.ViewController',
    alias: 'controller.intranetcontainer',
    onGridEditorIntraEdit: function (editor, ctx, eOpts) {
        //combobox
        var vendorColIdx = 2;
        var combo = ctx.grid.columns[vendorColIdx].getEditor(ctx.record);
        var vendorRecord = combo.findRecord('name', combo.getValue());
        console.log(vendorRecord);
        ctx.record.set('specuserId', vendorRecord.get('id'));
        //tagfield
        var vendorColIdx = 3;
        var tagfields = ctx.grid.columns[vendorColIdx].getEditor(ctx.record);
        var valuetag = tagfields.getValue();
        //ctx.record.set('mainusersId', vendorRecord.get('id'));
       //ctx.record.set(valuetag);
       //console.log(ctx.record);
        //ctx.grid.getStore().sync();
    }
});
```

First I get the id of the selected `combobox` values ​​and set it to send to the server, and then I try to get the id of the selected `tagfields` values ​​to send them to the server, but I don’t get it right.
How to make the id of the selected values ​​with `tagfield` go to the server.
Thanks.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by not getting it right? What do you actually get in `valuetag`?

Comment: @scebotari66  I get the values, but I need the id values ​​to send them to the server

Comment: That's because you have specified "name" for the tagfield's `valueField` config. Try specifying "id"

Comment: @scebotari66 When I specify the ID in the valueField config, the saved values ​​in the tagfield field are displayed as id, I need to be in the form of a name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since setting the tagfield's `displayField` to "name" prevents getting the array of selected record ids, another way to achieve this is by using tagfield's [getValueRecords](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.7.0/classic/Ext.form.field.Tag.html#method-getValueRecords) method. We can pass the result of this method to the [Array's map function](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.7.0/classic/Ext.Array.html#method-map) and gather only the ids:

```
var tagfieldSeletedIds = Ext.Array.map(tagfield.getValueRecords(), function(record) {
    return record.getId()
});
```

Comment: I did it and it works. thank.

`var tagfields = ctx.grid.columns[vendorColIdx].getEditor(ctx.record);
var tagfieldSeletedIds = Ext.Array.map(tagfields.getValueRecords(), function(record) {
    return record.getId()
});
ctx.record.set('users_id', tagfieldSeletedIds);
ctx.grid.getStore().sync();`